# Semantic-based sentiment classification using NLTK

Tags: nlp, nltk

I am trying to build a feedback sentiment analyser based on a semantic approach. As an example: "I had safe journey" – assume this is feedback for a driver, provided by a passenger. I need to extract the following information from this sentence:

```
"I had safe journey" -> 
 SUBJECT= "driving"
 SENTIMENT= "positive"
```

I am using NLTK and I referred NLTK Book. I already followed the "Extracting Information from Text" section. That section talks about Chunking using a regular-expression based grammar. But I am confused, there are a number of different sentence patterns for the English language and I don't know how to cover all the possibilities.

Actually, I am new to NLP. I also found "Analyzing Sentence Structure" and "Analyzing the Meaning of Sentences" in the NLTK book. Is chunking enough to achieve  my goal and what am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily have to do parsing or chunking. Both detection of the subject and of the sentiment polarity might be achieved with plain bag-of-words based clasifiers at a sufficient level of quality. It depends on the nature of your input text (how long they are, how many spelling/grammar errors there are, how many different subjects...) and on your needs (eg. if you are happy with 80% accuracy already).

What you most certainly need, however, is either a training set of already classified instances, or a good polarity lexicon. If you don't have either, parsing/chunking won't help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

- **Supervised learning:** a [Naive Bayes classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) would be appropriate. It is efficient but you need a training set.
- **Lexicon-based approach:** if you don't have a training set, you can use a list of polarized words. You should do some reseach about [SentiWordNet](http://sentiwordnet.isti.cnr.it), [MPQA](http://mpqa.cs.pitt.edu/) or [SentiStrength](http://sentistrength.wlv.ac.uk/). (Bonus: you also can have a look at [WordNet-Affect](http://wndomains.fbk.eu/wnaffect.html) which provides a tree of emotions. It is quite old but you still can use it with the [WNAffect interface](https://github.com/clemtoy/WNAffect))

But first of all you should tokenize your text. With NLTK, you can use Punkt calling `nltk.word_tokenize()`.